# clang microsoft-template under linux?

Tags: c++, clang

I'm building a embedded database with c++,  and I'm using a non-standard feature of c++ template--- explicit specialization of a templated member function in enclosing class definition body, yes, this is supported in msvc as many ppl know, and this is not supported by gcc, and I need my database support linux.

so, I tried llvm/clang, and I found clang compiles the featured code under windows, but when I was using clang precompiled binary under fedora 27, compilation failed.

so, is there a method to let me compile "explicit specialization of a templated member function in enclosing class definition body" under linux? Maybe some ./configure cmake option should be added to clang src building process?

for ref, clang provides -Wmicrosft-template as a warning option.
Thanks for replies ahead.

Comment: Could you please add some capital letters and paragraph breaks to your question so it's easier to read? Remember, sentences in English end with a full stop: `.`.

Comment: Can I ask why you don't refactor your code to be valid C++, instead? Why did you choose a non-standard, non-portable extension?

Comment: Oh, \r\n is added when im editing, but it's not here. Yes, i will edit it asap

Comment: yea, I considered it logically yesterday --- the standard bans it, there should be a somewhat equivalent grammar for my code, and, I found it. It uses function override, pretty straight forward, but need a box class to wrap a null-use function parameter as a cost which I don't care. But my code uses this feature not only once, this will make my code pretty ugly